# add event to button in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim txt As New TextBox()
    Dim btn As New Button()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        btn.Name = "btnMove"
        btn.Size = New Size(60, 20)
        btn.Location = New Point(220, 20)
        btn.Text = "move"
        btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
        Me.BringToFront()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMove_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

this is my code and i want to add an event to btn Button i hope that i make my problem clear and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Well you've already added the `btnMove_Click` handler to `btn` using `Handles btn.Click` - in what way does it not work?

Comment: @JonSkeet: His code has deeper problems; he's trying to misuse an array.

Comment: @JonSkeet Handles clause requires a With Events variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types

Comment: Maybe code wouldn't compile since btn whould be declared with the `WithEvents` statement   `Dim WithEvents btn As New Button()` to be able to use the `Handles btn.Click`

Comment: You are welcome :). I will see it there is no evident duplicate of this issue. If not I could remove my comment with typos and write it as an answer.

Comment: @AyshaAlmaqtari: In future, please make sure you include the error message in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Private Sub btnMove_Click(...) Handles btn.Click
```

The *Handles* keyword requires you to declare the control that generates the event with the *WithEvents* keyword.  Fix:

```
   Dim WithEvents btn As New Button()
```

The alternative is to subscribe the event explicitly with the AddHandler keyword.  In which case you omit the *Handles* keyword and write it like this instead:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(...) Handles MyBase.Load
   '' etc..
   AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnMove_click
End Sub
```

Using the designer to add these controls is certainly the best way, it avoids little mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim btn As New Button
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        btn.Name = "btnMove"
        btn.Size = New Size(60, 20)
        btn.Location = New Point(220, 30)
        btn.Text = "Move"
        btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
        Me.BringToFront()
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btnMove_click
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnMove_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MsgBox("welcome to salfkjsadlkf")
    End Sub
End Class
```